# Can I put a group of objects within a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JSON to return an array of objects identical to each other in variable names, but differing in values. Rather than call the JSON function five times, is there a way that I can put objects within the JSON object so I can reference them like data.1.name, data.2.name, etc?

Current (terrible) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
            var data = 'manliness=' + $("#manliness_level_number").html() + '&type=enemy';
            load_opponents();

            function load_opponents()
            {
                $.getJSON('http://arflux-rpg.com/game/index.php/handler/request', data, function(data){
                    if (data.success == true)
                    {
                        $("#enemy_list").append("<div id='" + data.name + "' class='enemy'><img class='enemy_image' src='http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=100x100' /><div class='enemy_manliness'>" + data.manliness + "</div><div class='enemy_richliness_reward'>"+data.richliness_reward+"</div><div class='enemy_manliness_reward'>"+data.manliness_reward+"</div></div>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('Failed to load enemies and users! ' + data.err);
                    }
                });
            }
[code cut from here for brevity]
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the code that is generating this JSON. Can you show us the relevant PHP code?

Comment: FYI, what you are talking about isn't a **JSON object** but a **JSON compatible object** - pedantic yes but still important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the objects in an array and then convert the array to JSON.  Then you can access them as `data[1].name` and `data[2].name` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an array:

```
var data = [ { "name": "one"},
             { "name":"two"},
             { "name":"three"} ];
```

Then reference it like this:

```
data[i].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just push the responding data into an array :)

```
var myArray = [];

$.getJSON('http://arflux-rpg.com/game/index.php/handler/request', data, function(data){
    if (data.success == true) {

        myArray.push(data);

    } else {
        alert('Failed to load enemies and users! ' + data.err);
    }
});
```

It's that easy :)